# Is it neceassry to extends SQLiteOpenHelper?

Tags: android, sqlite

Is it necessary to extends SQLiteOpenHelper.I just want to copy the database(read only)  from aseets folder.

Comment: if you want to just copy it and do nothing with it... it is not necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not necessary to extends SQLiteOpenHelper,To create and upgrade a database in your Android application you usually subclass "SQLiteOpenHelper". In this class you need to override the methods onCreate() to create the database and onUpgrade() to upgrade the database in case of changes in the database schema. Both methods receive an "SQLiteDatabase" object.

SQLiteOpenHelper provides the methods getReadableDatabase() and getWriteableDatabase() to get access to an "SQLiteDatabase" object which allows database access either in read or write mode.

For the primary key of the database you should always use the identifier "_id" as some of Android functions rely on this standard.

Comment: -1 you are wrong ... it is not *necessary*, the helper class is exactly that ... a helper, and is merely provided for convenience.

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to copy the database then its fine.
But if you want to read,update,delete or create  new record in database then there are two ways

1. Extend sqlitedatabase
2. Use ormlite wrapper

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, **it not need** ,if you just want copy database file and don`t operate database, it just a file **I/O operate**.

Comment: Please take more care answering questions, formatting is an answer correctly takes a little more time, but it worth it